# How do I access video output capabilities on iOS?

Tags: ios, video

Applications such as Netflix have the ability to play video out of the dock connector when the video connector is hooked up.  Do applications have the ability to put arbitrary data on video out?  Or is the video player the only component on iOS that can do so?  If the former is possible, how can my app access video output?

Comment: There is this amazing little package on github that handles the entire process. You literally need to add one line to your code. http://www.touchcentric.com/blog/archives/123

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To draw to video out, place a window on the screen returned by `[[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];`. Call `window.screen = theScreen` on a window you have already created to assign it to the screen "theScreen".